# How to display a phtml in a backend custom menu

Tags: backend, adminhtml, controllers, cms

I've created a new menu on the backend, called "X" with an item called "Y". When I click on this item, it appears nowhere because I don't know how to display it. Let me show you what I have done.

In the cotroller.php I have put this:

```
public function indexAction()
    {
 $block = $this->getLayout()
        ->createBlock('core/text', 'example-block')
        ->setText(‘Hello’);
        $this->_addContent($block);

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

For this code, if I click on the menu "Y", I get the output "Hello". Ok, but now I don't know how to call a phtml or something in order to display whatever I want.

I don’t know how to call another cms/block or something like that to watch it there. Using this code snippet:

```
$this->getlayout()->createBlock('cms/block')->setBlockId('my-cms')->to
Html();
```

(where my-cms is a cms page that I created before)

the output appears at the top, so it doesn’t work the way I want it to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Putting your two code snippets together, I get:

```
public function indexAction()
    {
       $block = $this->getLayout()
       ->createBlock('cms/block')
       ->setBlockId('my-cms');
        $this->_addContent($block);

        $this->renderLayout();
    }
```

Have you tried this?

Comment: omggg, really?! I tried that but with "toHtml()" at the end.. omg..
YES, your code works.
Thanks a lot !!


EDIT: One more question.. if I want to put PHP code to that CMS (because creating that CMS from cms->static block, didn't let me to put php code).. how can I do that? Really thanks a lot.

Comment: @inavas To use PHP code, you should create your own block type, which extends from Mage_Core_Block_Template which has an associated template (phtml) file. In the phtml template, you can then call all your blocks methods using $this->...
Another possibility is to directly use PHP code in the phtml template by using a block of "core/template", but this is not good style and you should really avoid this.

Comment: I see, I will try the first option then. Thanks a lot ! :)

Comment: Hi, sorry to disturb you again.. I tried to create a new template and I failed.. so I tried the "easy way" that was creating a new .phtml on /template/customphp/mycode.phtml and call it in different ways but it doesnt appear.. I try it with: $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('customphp/mycode.phtml') but it appears nothing. So I try calling a cms/block that calls "mycode.phtml": {{block type="core/template" template="customphp/mycode.phtml"}}
but nothign... what I am doing wrongggg? Sorry to disturb, but it's very important for me knowing this. THANKS!!

Comment: @inavas Did you insert the template to the correct design folder? What is the path before /template?
Also, did you still use $this->_addContent($block); ?
Besides, your code looks correct and should work.

Comment: thanks for your answer. Yes, I think I have insert the template on the correct desing folder. I insert it in (app/design/frontend/default/modern/template) and in (app/design/frontend/default/default/template) because I wasn't sure where to insert it, at least one has to work. And yes, the code was:
$block = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('customphp/mycode.‌​phtml')
$this->_addContent($block);

But it doesn't work.. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @inavas I suggest you create a new question for this and give as much detail as possible, i.e. describe all steps you have done, post the content of your template file etc. Then someone will be able to help you. :) Cheers

Comment: I got it!!! I was inserting it "...app/design/FRONTEND" how stupid.. I insert it now in "app/design/ADMINHTML/.. etc" and now works!! Thanks for all :)